# Integral inequality on $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb C$ . Suppose for every $z \in \mathbb C$, il exists a positive function $M : \mathbb C \to \mathbb R^+$ such that $|f(z)| \leq M(z)$. Is it true that, for any path $C$, we always have: $\displaystyle\int_C |f(z)| dz \leq \displaystyle\int_C M(z) dz$. If not, what conditions should we impose so that this inequality is true?

Comment: If you take the path $z(t) = it$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$, then neither integral is real, so the inequality is meaningless.

Comment: In general, $\int_C M(z)\,dz$ is not real, even if $M$ is.  There is an inequality that looks like $\int_C M(z) \,|dz|$, however.  Think of $|dz|$ as the element of arc length.

Comment: thanks! What if I take the modules of both integrals. Will it be true?

Answer (score 0):

You can say two things here: first, $\left| \int \limits _C f(z) {\rm d} z \right| \le \int \limits _C | f(z) |  | {\rm d} z |$; second, $\int \limits _C | f(z) | | {\rm d} z | \le \int \limits _C M(z) | {\rm d} z |$. Here, if $c : [a,b] \to \Bbb C$ is a parametrization of $C$, then $| {\rm d} z | = |c' (t)| {\rm d} t$.